# Returning a boolean and using it in other methods and objects

Tags: java, boolean, return

I am to create a clock displaying Military and Normal time in two different classes and time declared as objects.That is done but now i need to extend the `clock` class into a 
`AMPMclock` that has the `setAMPM(boolean yes)` method in it. If the `setAMPM(true)` it will display the military time and if it is false it will display the Normal time. I create the `setAMPM` method

```
class AMPMclock extends clock
{
    boolean setAMPM(boolean yes)
    { 
        return yes;
    }  
}
```

---

```
class clock
{
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;
private boolean yes;

    setMin....

    setHour...

    setSec....

    tick() ///moves the clock 1sec


    public String toString()
    {

        if(yes) return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", (hours == 12 || hours == 0)?12 : hours%12, minutes, seconds, (hours < 12)? "AM" : "PM");
        else return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hours,minutes,seconds);
    //else 
    }
```

}

---

MAIN

```
AMPMclock clockObject = new AMPMclock();

clockObject.setHour(16);
clockObject.setMin(28);
clockObject.setSec(58);



    System.out.println(clockObject.toString());
    clockObject.tick();
    clockObject.setAMPM(false);
    System.out.println(clockObject.toString());

    clockObject.tick();
    clockObject.setAMPM(true);
    System.out.println(clockObject.toString());
    clockObject.tick();
    System.out.println(clockObject.toString());
```

However whet i use `clockObject.setAMPM(true)` or `clockObject.setAMPM(false)`
the yes boolean will not change so i can use it in another method. It always stay the same...Any help? Tnx

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.  Please add some code that illustrates the problem you're having.

Comment: This code hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a setter is to encapsulate a private instance variable. You are simply returning the parameter back without modifying the internal state of the class, which is why nothing "sticks" in your code.

```
class Clock {

     private boolean useAMPM;

     public void setAMPM(boolean useAMPM) {
         this.useAMPM = useAMPM;
     }

     public boolean isAMPM() {
         return this.useAMPM;
     }
}
```

Comment: Just to adjust to the Java Bean standards, the getter should be `isAMPM()`.

Comment: ok but i need to use the useAMPM as well inside the "clock" class.
i declare the "private boolean useAMPM;" but it is not recognized even though the clock is extended.

Comment: @StefanosVarsanis, if AMPM is only relevant to the subclass, I would be tempted to let it simply be an implementation detail of the subclass and possibly override ToString if need be. Otherwise, you will need to put the variable in the super class and open it up, possibly using the `protected` keyword instead of `private` so that subclasses can see it. The downside is that any class in the same package would *also* be able to see it. You'll have to evaluate each approach to see what best fits your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Antony.I changed the variables into protected and overrode the toString method.Will try to see a different solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you save a setting for example in an ampm instance variable, then you need something like:

```
boolean ampm = true;

boolean setAMPM(boolean yes)
{
    ampm = yes;
    return yes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to follow java bean conventions ?

Is this what you are aiming to achieve ?

```
public class AMPMClock {

  private boolean isAMPM;

  public void setAMPM(boolean ampmFlag){
    this.isAMPM = ampmFlag;
  }
  public boolean isAMPM(){
   return this.isAMPM;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to store that in a member variable…

```
    private boolean useAMPM = false;
    public boolean setAMPM (final boolean wantAMPM) {
          useAMPM = wantAMPM;
          return useAMPM;
    }
    public void draw () {
            … 
          if (useAMPM) { /* … */ } else { /* … */ }
    }
```

The variables in a method's lambda list (the ones you specify when you define a method, like `wantAMPM`/`yes`) are assigned when the function is called, and destroyed when the function returns. (It's a good habit to declare them all `final`, for various reasons, as well.) In fact, you can also create *automatic* variables within (almost) any pair of `{ braces }` in a Java program, which will likewise be destroyed when you reach the end of the `}` block.

*Member* variables (properties) are kept around for the lifetime of the object instance in which they're found. So when, e.g. you say `Clock clockInstance = new Clock ();`, then `clock.useAMPM` will be created, and continue to exist until `clockInstance` is destroyed.